# Trouble Installing IPFS

Tags: macos, npm, permissions, installation, ipfs

I am using the instructions given on their site for MacOS- https://ipfs.io/docs/install/#installing-with-ipfs-update 
[tutorial][1]

To build demo, clone this repo and run the following command:

```
$ cd contracts
$ npm install
```

Running the demo
To run demo, first run testrpc by running:

```
$ testrpc
```

Then compile and deploy the solidity contracts:

```
$ truffle compile
$ truffle migrate
```

Run an instance of IPFS to enable uploads:

```
$ ipfs daemon
```

Finally to build website, run:

```
$ npm run dev
```

I reached this last step (npm run dev) and I got an error message saying "npm missing scripts dev"

I am in the contracts directory specified, and installed everything there properly I believe. However, I don't see any dev script in the json package(s) which I believe could be being referenced using the npm run dev command. May this be the problem?

Here are the files wihin the folder contracts-master

```
app

index.html
javascripts
stylesheets
contracts
**ethpm.json** This one?  
img
LICENSE
Lockup.sol
migrations
**package.json** Or this one?  
Readme.md
scripts
coverage.sh
coveralls.sh
install.sh
test.sh
truffle.js
```

Any help / suggestions / learning resources would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time,

Elias

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not because of ipfs. You are running dev mode but error saying that you don't have any scripts dev.If you are deploying smart contracts then you don't need ipfs demon. check package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "command to run service"
  }
```

Your package.json don't have dev scripts recheck package.json

Comment: Thanks, that's what i thought I just wanted to confirm with you guys, my professor and I took a look at all the files I downloaded from the git clone and couldn't find any package containing dev scripts. Looks like I'm going to have to build it myself from scratch. Their code is very piecemeal.